# Method to normalize the number of samples (rows)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am seeking a Python based solution that will group on the ID and find the mean of the data in different time Ranges.

```
Input Data

Id  Time    X1  Y1  X2  Y2  X3  Y3
A   0.08    427 351 427 351 427 353
A   0.15    384 365 384 365 384 367
A   0.24    125 190 196 404 196 406
A   0.39    468 342 468 342 398 375
A   0.47    171 457 171 457 171 460
A   0.53    1   343 1   343 1   345
A   0.66    139 328 139 328 139 330
B   0.04    152 179 152 181 150 183
B   0.19    74  75  123 400 123 404
B   0.26    117 99  117 104 116 105
B   0.39    156 125 156 131 71  209
B   0.47    187 147 189 155 187 157
B   0.03    272 340 278 361 249 442
B   0.14    272 351 275 354 250 420
C   0.26    279 347 279 347 266 384
C   0.37    271 337 283 348 258 377
```

Group on the ID and for find the Mean for X1,Y1,Y2,Y2,X3,Y3 in a range bases on the Frame.

The Mean of all X,y values for a Grouped ID would be calculated for Frames in the following ranges.  If there are no x,y values in that range return NaN

```
1 = (Time <= .1)
2 = (.1 <= Time <= .2)
3 = (.2 <= Time <= .3)
4 = (.3 <= Time <= .4)
5 = (.4 <= Time <= .5)
6 = (.5 <= Time <= .6)
7 = (.6 <= Time <= .7)
8 = (.7 <= Time <= .8)
9 = (.8 <= Time <= .9)


Id  1X1 1Y1 1X2 1Y2 1X3 1Y3  ... 9X3    9Y3  
A   427 351 427 351 427 353
A   384 365 384 365 384 367
A   125 190 196 404 196 406
A   468 342 468 342 398 375
A   171 457 171 457 171 460
A   1   343 1   343 1   345
A   139 328 139 328 139 330
B   152 179 152 181 150 183
B   74  75  123 400 123 404
B   117 99  117 104 116 105
B   156 125 156 131 71  209
B   187 147 189 155 187 157
B   272 340 278 361 249 442
B   272 351 275 354 250 420
C   279 347 279 347 266 384
C   271 337 283 348 258 377
```

Comment: Did you consider using Pandas package?; this problem could be easily done with it. just using groupby by two columns: `Id` and by `pd.cut(df.Time, bins=pd.np.arange(10)/10)`.

Comment: I am a python novice and I could use a bit more help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a misconception regarding your expected output. The numbers that you have appear to suggest that you are pivoting the Time bins along the rows, shown in the steps below. However, at the same time, the column names suggest that you are also pivoting the bin dimension, against each of the X, Y variable along the columns - though you provided no numbers for those.

Here are the steps leading to the output having Time bins residing on the rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

>>>df
   Id  Time   X1   Y1   X2   Y2   X3   Y3
0   A  0.08  427  351  427  351  427  353
1   A  0.15  384  365  384  365  384  367
2   A  0.24  125  190  196  404  196  406
3   A  0.39  468  342  468  342  398  375
4   A  0.47  171  457  171  457  171  460
5   A  0.53    1  343    1  343    1  345
6   A  0.66  139  328  139  328  139  330
7   B  0.04  152  179  152  181  150  183
8   B  0.19   74   75  123  400  123  404
9   B  0.26  117   99  117  104  116  105
10  B  0.39  156  125  156  131   71  209
11  B  0.47  187  147  189  155  187  157
12  B  0.03  272  340  278  361  249  442
13  B  0.14  272  351  275  354  250  420
14  C  0.26  279  347  279  347  266  384
15  C  0.37  271  337  283  348  258  377

# This is the base operation that you're looking for to produce the output in your example
df = df.groupby(['Id', pd.cut(df['Time'], np.arange(0, 1.0, 0.1))]).mean()
>>>df
                Time     X1     Y1     X2     Y2     X3     Y3
Id Time
A  (0.0, 0.1]  0.080  427.0  351.0  427.0  351.0  427.0  353.0
   (0.1, 0.2]  0.150  384.0  365.0  384.0  365.0  384.0  367.0
   (0.2, 0.3]  0.240  125.0  190.0  196.0  404.0  196.0  406.0
   (0.3, 0.4]  0.390  468.0  342.0  468.0  342.0  398.0  375.0
   (0.4, 0.5]  0.470  171.0  457.0  171.0  457.0  171.0  460.0
   (0.5, 0.6]  0.530    1.0  343.0    1.0  343.0    1.0  345.0
   (0.6, 0.7]  0.660  139.0  328.0  139.0  328.0  139.0  330.0
   (0.7, 0.8]    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
   (0.8, 0.9]    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
B  (0.0, 0.1]  0.035  212.0  259.5  215.0  271.0  199.5  312.5
   (0.1, 0.2]  0.165  173.0  213.0  199.0  377.0  186.5  412.0
   (0.2, 0.3]  0.260  117.0   99.0  117.0  104.0  116.0  105.0
   (0.3, 0.4]  0.390  156.0  125.0  156.0  131.0   71.0  209.0
   (0.4, 0.5]  0.470  187.0  147.0  189.0  155.0  187.0  157.0
   (0.5, 0.6]    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
   (0.6, 0.7]    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
   (0.7, 0.8]    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
   (0.8, 0.9]    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
C  (0.0, 0.1]    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
   (0.1, 0.2]    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
   (0.2, 0.3]  0.260  279.0  347.0  279.0  347.0  266.0  384.0
   (0.3, 0.4]  0.370  271.0  337.0  283.0  348.0  258.0  377.0
   (0.4, 0.5]    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
   (0.5, 0.6]    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
   (0.6, 0.7]    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
   (0.7, 0.8]    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
   (0.8, 0.9]    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN

"""
The rest are just cosmetics
"""
# Drop the original Time column
df.drop('Time', axis=1, inplace=True)
# Reset the index
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
# Add a numerical label for the Time bins
df['TimeNo'] = (df.index % 9) + 1
# Rearrange the columns
df = df.iloc[:,[0,1,8]].join(df.iloc[:,2:8])
# Drop the NaN rows
df = df.loc[np.sum(df.iloc[:,3:], axis=1)>0]

>>>df
   Id        Time  TimeNo     X1     Y1     X2     Y2     X3     Y3
0   A  (0.0, 0.1]       1  427.0  351.0  427.0  351.0  427.0  353.0
1   A  (0.1, 0.2]       2  384.0  365.0  384.0  365.0  384.0  367.0
2   A  (0.2, 0.3]       3  125.0  190.0  196.0  404.0  196.0  406.0
3   A  (0.3, 0.4]       4  468.0  342.0  468.0  342.0  398.0  375.0
4   A  (0.4, 0.5]       5  171.0  457.0  171.0  457.0  171.0  460.0
5   A  (0.5, 0.6]       6    1.0  343.0    1.0  343.0    1.0  345.0
6   A  (0.6, 0.7]       7  139.0  328.0  139.0  328.0  139.0  330.0
9   B  (0.0, 0.1]       1  212.0  259.5  215.0  271.0  199.5  312.5
10  B  (0.1, 0.2]       2  173.0  213.0  199.0  377.0  186.5  412.0
11  B  (0.2, 0.3]       3  117.0   99.0  117.0  104.0  116.0  105.0
12  B  (0.3, 0.4]       4  156.0  125.0  156.0  131.0   71.0  209.0
13  B  (0.4, 0.5]       5  187.0  147.0  189.0  155.0  187.0  157.0
20  C  (0.2, 0.3]       3  279.0  347.0  279.0  347.0  266.0  384.0
21  C  (0.3, 0.4]       4  271.0  337.0  283.0  348.0  258.0  377.0
```

As you can see, with this output format, you wouldn't need to place your Time bin in the columns.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Thank you for the help!